# C. double free or corruption (!prev) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, memory-management, ansi-c

I'm trying to use a "fixed memory scheme" and pre-allocate memory & reuse it via alloc, init, free fashion as many times as possible.

free() will called at shutdown only, but I want to test many iterations.

Although I call my alloc function  `bn_tree_alloc_node_space_heap()` & init function `bn_tree_init_node_heap()`, I can only call free function `bn_tree_free_node_space` once.

**Below is a complete reproducible snippet of my memory management, maint_test.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#define BN_TREE_HEAP_SIZE 100

/*variables internal*/
typedef struct bntree_internals;

/*bn_tree_node is single bntree_t leaf*/
typedef struct bn_tree_node {
    struct bn_tree_node* left;
    struct bn_tree_node* right;
    float* dataset;
    float distance_to_neighbor;
    int visited;
    int heap_index;
} bn_tree_node;

/*tree*/
typedef struct {
    /*in order to  keep track of the bn-tree root*/
    bn_tree_node* _root;
    /*pointer to internal variables struct*/
    struct bntree_internals* _internals;

} bntree_t;


/*bn tree leaf nodes heap*/
bn_tree_node* node_processing_space = NULL;

/*leaf nodes*/
void bn_tree_alloc_node_space_heap(int max_dimensions);
bn_tree_node*
get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap();
void bn_tree_init_node_heap(bn_tree_node* nodes, int max_dimensions);
void bn_tree_free_node_space(bn_tree_node* nodes);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /*PROBLEM:called the alloc,init,free cycle several times, problem, 
     getting seg fault on 2nd call of free()*/
    bn_tree_alloc_node_space_heap(3);
    assert(get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap());
    printf("alloc\n");
    bn_tree_init_node_heap(node_processing_space, 3);
    printf("init\n");
    bn_tree_free_node_space(node_processing_space);
    printf("free\n");

    bn_tree_alloc_node_space_heap(3);
    assert(get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap());
    printf("alloc\n");
    bn_tree_init_node_heap(node_processing_space, 3);
    printf("init\n");
    bn_tree_free_node_space(node_processing_space);
    printf("free\n");

    bn_tree_alloc_node_space_heap(3);
    assert(get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap());
    printf("alloc\n");
    bn_tree_init_node_heap(node_processing_space, 3);
    printf("init\n");
    bn_tree_free_node_space(node_processing_space);
    printf("free\n");

    bn_tree_alloc_node_space_heap(3);
    assert(get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap());
    printf("alloc\n");
    bn_tree_init_node_heap(node_processing_space, 3);
    printf("init\n");
    bn_tree_free_node_space(node_processing_space);
    printf("free\n");



    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void bn_tree_alloc_node_space_heap(int max_dimensions) {
    if (NULL == node_processing_space) {
        node_processing_space = (bn_tree_node*) calloc(BN_TREE_HEAP_SIZE, sizeof (bn_tree_node));


        //TODO: bn_tree_set_k_dimensions (max_dimensions);

        int i = 0;
        for (; i < BN_TREE_HEAP_SIZE; i++) {
            node_processing_space[i].dataset = (float*) calloc(max_dimensions, sizeof (float));

        }

        //bn_heap_tail_index = bn_heap_head_index = 0;
    }
}

bn_tree_node* get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap() {
    return node_processing_space;
}

void bn_tree_init_node_heap(bn_tree_node* nodes, int max_dimensions) {

    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for (; i < BN_TREE_HEAP_SIZE; i++) {

        /*reset  values */
        if (NULL != nodes[i].dataset) {
            c = 0;
            for (; c < max_dimensions; c++) {
                nodes[i].dataset[c] = FLT_MIN;
            }
        }
        nodes[i].visited = 0;
        nodes[i].distance_to_neighbor = FLT_MAX;
        nodes[i].left = NULL;
        nodes[i].right = NULL;
        nodes[i].heap_index = -1;

    }
}


/*PROBLEM is subsequent call to free(), but if I alloc again why cant I free again?*/
void bn_tree_free_node_space(bn_tree_node* nodes) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < BN_TREE_HEAP_SIZE; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].dataset) {
            free(nodes[i].dataset);
        }
    }

    free(nodes);
    nodes = NULL;
}
```

**Here is the output that I expect/want:**

```
alloc
init
free
alloc
init
free
alloc
init
free
alloc
init
free
```

**But Im getting this output/error:**

```
alloc
init
free
alloc
init
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

1. How can fix this?
2. Can't I do alloc,init,free as many times as I want (as long as I called alloc before free) OR I can do only alloc() once, then many init(), free() once?

Thanks a million & please be kind enough to provide concise answers with minimal changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your  `bn_tree_free_node_space` function takes, as its argument, a **copy** of the pointer variable - that is, you are passing the pointer *by value* - thus, the line `nodes = NULL;` at the end of that function only sets the *local* variable to `NULL` and *does not change the value of* the `node_processing_space` variable.

To fix this (with minimal changes to your code logic<sup>1</sup>), you need to pass that function a *pointer to the pointer*, and dereference that in the function. So, your function should look like this:

```c
void bn_tree_free_node_space(bn_tree_node** nodes) // Argument is pointer-to-pointer
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < BN_TREE_HEAP_SIZE; i++) {
        if ((*nodes)[i].dataset) { // Now we need to use (*nodes) to get the underlying pointer
            free((*nodes)[i].dataset); // ... same here
        }
    }

    free(*nodes); /// ... and here
    *nodes = NULL;
}
```

You will, of course, also need to change the function prototype (just before your `main`) to match the new definition:

```c
void bn_tree_free_node_space(bn_tree_node** nodes); // Must match definition!
```

Fruther, you will (clearly) need to change the calls to that function to pass the *address* of the `node_processing_space` pointer:

```c
bn_tree_free_node_space(&node_processing_space); // Likewise for the other 3 calls!
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

---

<sup>1</sup> EDIT: There are other ways (some may argue *better* ways) to implement your system, and also other 'minor' issues in your code. However, you did *explicitly* ask for "concise answers with minimal changes," so I have endeavoured to comply with that request!

Comment: thanks. So if  a pointer gets passed a function with pointer* signature the pointer is dereferenced automatically & the value is passed in?

Comment: @cyber101 Not really. There's is no automatic dereferencing but the pointer is treated just like any other type of argument that is passed by value: your function can change what it *points to* but not its actual value. In your case, you want (need) to change the *value* of the pointer (i.e. assign a new, `NULL` address value to it), so you have to pass a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: Got it thanks.  What if I wanted to pass in node_processing_space using the getter function like     `bn_tree_init_node_heap(get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap(), 3);` the call `bn_tree_init_node_heap(&get_pre_allocated_bn_tree_node_heap(), 3);` causes compile error "lvalue..."